# Is it possible to have a resistor network whose total value is unsolvable?

Tags: resistors, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law

Home hobbyist here. I've been doing a lot of theoretical resistor, voltage divider, Ohm's law, and Kirchhoff law type problems just for practice, and ran across this [older video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JK_hCYnKtGk) on YouTube, which presented this problem:

[image]

I didn't have a problem solving it, but it got me to thinking: Is it possible to come up with a resistor network type problem like this which isn't solvable?

Comment: You can always build it, apply a voltage across it and measure the current.

Comment: Yes, I understand it can be measured, I'm just wondering if there's one which could be mathematically unsolvable.

Comment: Or simulate it with LTspice or equivalent.

Comment: Yep, understand that too. What about my original question?

Comment: All finite resistor networks are solvable. If you want a rigorous proof, you will have to look elsewhere.

Comment: Computers do math.  Spice is building up a system of equations and then solving them, so a spice simulation is a mathematical solution to the problem. I think in the case of a linear network made of ideal components like this, it is even doing the same math you would, or at least something pretty close.

Comment: Even if you have a physically impossible circuit, such as a resistor ladder which continues infinitely, you are still able to calculate the resistance of the network when length of the ladder approaches infinity.

Comment: ITT: https://xkcd.com/356/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have two terminals to a network of resistors, the resistance between the two terminals will always be a single value.

This is a special case of [Thevenin's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem), without the complicating voltage and current sources. The wikipedia article linked has a proof of this theorem.

If the network is infinite and general, then there will be a computation impossibility for a general circuit, not surprising as the network cannot be represented in a finite way. In order to define it, the connectivity and resistor values will usually employ some symmetries, [for instance ...](https://xkcd.com/356/), which allow a computation to be made.

For a finite network, application of series, parallel and delta-Y transformations allow any network to be reduced down to a single equivalent resistance in O(n) time.

Although any finite network can be reduced to an equivalent resistance, the network cannot necessarily be fully solved in the sense of determining all branch currents when a voltage is applied. If the network contains some zero resistance elements, then the branch currents may be ambiguous. This is what happens in SPICE if you have loops of zero impedance, you get an uninvertible matrix.

Comment: @psmears I think I mean O(n) time. However, an ohmmeter can do it in O(1)!

Comment: Haha, fair point :)

Answer (score 4):

As long as you only allow a nonnegative resistance, then you can solve it. If you also include negative resistances then you can have a problem, for example:
What is equivalent resistance of a 10 Ω and a -10 Ω resistor connected in parallel?

While negative resistors dont exist, you can build active device that behave as one. Also, some passive device can exhibit negative resistance region, for example tunnel diode.

Comment: For 1V, you will have 0.1A in one resistor and 0.1A out the other resistor, so 0A total, so why can't I just say the two resistors in parallel are an open circuit (equivalent R is therefore infinity)?

Comment: It isnt so easy, problem is that R isnt only infinity, but have some extra properties, for example can you actually change voltage over it? With ∞ Ω there is zero current from outside, so it should keep voltage over them at 0 V no matter outside voltage and this sound like a paradox to me.

Comment: @Rotka why should it keep voltage at 0? In your example with 1 V, there is 1 V over both resistors, no current from outside, and 0.1 A of current looping through the two resistors. I don't see a paradox. A negative resistor generates power, so it is not a paradox that current flows only through the two resistors and not through the 1 V generator.

Comment: I think it is like the resonance in a parallel LC circuit , the inductive reactance is jXl and the capacitive reactance is -jXc so at resonance when Xl = Xc no current flows because the currents are 180 degrees out of phase.

Comment: @Rokta The combination of +10Ω, -10Ω and a voltage source all in parallel is fine. No current flows in the source, and all current flows in the resistor loop. Those resistors can have any voltage across them. It sure looks weird, but the maths works out fine in an application of KCL, KVL and Ohm's law, nodal analysis yields solvable equations. It's only conversion from a parallel pair to a single resistance that's problematic.

Answer (score 1):

All finite resistor networks are solvable because you can write a finite number of linear equations for such a network and solve the system of equations.

Comment: This is an incomplete proof because not all finite systems of linear equations are solvable. (For example x+y=3, x+2y=5, x+3y=8)

Comment: To expand on @user253751 's point further, for example a disconnected graph will give a singular matrix -- which can be shown by attempting to solve one with SPICE for example (assuming RSHUNT is disabled). We can see by inspection that such subgraphs either do not participate in the measurement, or we measure between them and get zero or infinite resistance; but expressing this in general terms is a little more tricky.

Comment: @user253751 your example equations cannot have been derived from the same system, because they aren't consistent with each other. They effectively say y=2 and y=3. If we apply KCL, KVL and Ohm's law consistently in a single system, none of the equations will contradict any other. I agree, though that for certain values of resistance, current or voltage, that one or more things may remain undefined, but not algebraically inconsistent.

Comment: @user253751 In addition to Simon Fitch's excellent comment your system of equations doesnt describe a electrical circuit  because the # of uknown variables will be equal to the  # of nodes or the # of meshes (depending on if you use KVL or KCL to solve a circuit).

Comment: @SimonFitch: What you say is true, but the point is that the answer just says "you can write a finite number of linear equations and solve" - but that's incomplete, because you actually need (and get, in the case of applying circuit laws to a circuit) stronger conditions in order to guarantee consistency.

Comment: @psmears No my answer is perfectly fine.Writing # of equations equal to the # of nodes or meshes is obvious.

Comment: @appliedSciences the answer as written is circular. "it is solvable because you can write a system of equations and solve it". Ok... why? Why is it guaranteed to be solvable?

Comment: @appliedSciences: But how do we _know_ that you won't sometimes, for some resistor networks, get a system of equations that is inconsistent or underdetermined?

Comment: Because such network doesnt exist?

Comment: @appliedSciences: That's the original question though! OP: "Is there a network we can't solve?" Your answer: "No, because we can make equations and solve them."  
user253751: "But what if the equations are inconsistent or underdetermined?" Your comment: "Such a network doesn't exist!"... do you see how circular that is?

Comment: The reasoninng isnt circular when it is true...

Comment: @appliedSciences: No, it's still circular, even if it's true! You need to give a justification for such a network not existing, or at least (if that's hard to do) acknowledge that fact. Otherwise your answer amounts to "No such network exists, because no such network exists", which isn't really an answer :)

Comment: @SimonFitch you have to **prove** they can't have been derived from the same system if you want to prove every system is solvable.

Comment: @appliedSciences "the sky is blue because the sky is blue" is circular - so is "the sky is green because the sky is green". Both proofs are equally valid so how do we know which colour the sky is?

Comment: @user253751 If I'm honest, all I have is intuition here. I *feel* that if a single system throws out equations that show some property to be both 2 and 3 at the same time, it's either quantum or fictitious, so I can only *suggest* that the equations came from different systems, or different instants in time of a single dynamic system. I have absolutely no clue how I'd prove that.

Comment: @SimonFitch it is proved by using your logic work.I have stopped caring for this line of comments because these people are just spitting random things they heard on the internet and they DO NOT provide any COUNTEREXAMPLES.

Comment: @appliedSciences I provided a counter-example to the claim "all systems of linear equations are solvable" in my very first comment.

Comment: @user253751 ok from your set of equations make a electrical circuit , post the link for the circuit and If it is correct I will admit I am wrong.

Comment: @appliedSciences why? the claim was about all systems of linear equations, not all electrical circuits

Comment: @user253751 I say "All finite resistor networks are solvable because you can write a finite number of linear equations for such a network and solve the system of equations."The circuit preexists the set of equations.In your case the set of equations preexist your hypothetical circuit , we use math to describe reality we dont describe reality from math.

Comment: so how do you know that you can solve the system of equations?

Comment: @user253751 ok then take your system and build a actual electrical circuit.

Comment: I can't because all electrical circuits are solvable. But how do you prove that? You need to give some explanation why that is true, in order for this to be a good answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144630/discussion-between-user253751-and-appliedsciences).